# Glmm plots look significant but summary not

Tags: r, model

I used glmer() to analyse binomial data and plot them out by ggplot.
The plot seemed to have siginificant differences under both x-asix variable A and group variable B, but the summary() showed there is no significant effect of their interaction.

[image: Graph of first model]

And then I changed the formula, removing the three-way interaction, fixed effect showed significant in new formula, but A:B is still insignificant.
Comparing AIC and R-square, and applying anova(), it's not significant between two models, but the first model's AIC and R-square are better than the latter.

Code as below:

```
# The first formula
glmm_model.1 <- glmer(Y~ A*B*C+(1|random),
                    family = binomial(link="logit"),  
                    data = data)

# Summary of glmm_model.1
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7284.2   7359.0  -3631.1   7262.2     6599 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.0345 -0.7168  0.2579  0.6361  3.7524 

Fixed effects:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                         -1.0693230  0.5603642  -1.908  0.05636 . 
A                                    0.0495183  0.0207214   2.390  0.01686 * 
B                                    0.7427204  0.6910692   1.075  0.28249   
C                                    0.0053335  0.0037191   1.434  0.15154   
A:B                                 -0.0048718  0.0297818  -0.164  0.87006   
A:C                                 -0.0002234  0.0001595  -1.400  0.16152   
B:C                                  0.0161719  0.0054922   2.945  0.00323 **
A:B:C                               -0.0003741  0.0002331  -1.605  0.10851   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1



# The latter formula
glmm_model.2 <- glmer(Y~ A*B+A*C+B*C+(1|random),
                      family = binomial(link="logit"),  
                      data = data)

# Summary of glmm_model.2
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7282.2   7343.3  -3632.1   7264.2     6601 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.8153 -0.7150  0.2543  0.6364  3.6107 


Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                    -1.3134516  0.5363266  -2.449  0.01433 *  
A                               0.0604615  0.0193618   3.123  0.00179 ** 
C                               0.0088813  0.0028810   3.083  0.00205 ** 
B                               1.3152630  0.5962002   2.206  0.02738 *  
A:C                            -0.0003815  0.0001186  -3.216  0.00130 ** 
B:C                             0.0076455  0.0018364   4.163 3.14e-05 ***
A:B                            -0.0302563  0.0252771  -1.197  0.23131    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Try as above,And then I changed the formula, removing the three-way interaction, fixed effect showed significant in new formula, but A:B is still insignificant, and the plot had no significant change

Comment: What is A, what is B, what is C and more important what is your question ?

Comment: A is x-asix variable and B is the group variable(red and blue line), I didn't use C in the plot. It's visible that in this graph, the peak in 16 is due to A and B 's interaction, but in summary A:B is insignificant which means the A-B interaction doesn't work on the response variable, I just wonder why this happened, the plot support my hypothesis but the analysis doesn't.